# AKS Query issue, Disk io per disk per node

Tags: azure-log-analytics

Facing issue while setting alert   to aks pod for disk read per second per node.

```
**InsightsMetrics
| where Namespace == 'container.azm.ms/diskio'
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| where Name == 'reads'
| extend Tags = todynamic(Tags)
| extend HostName = tostring(Tags.hostName), Device = Tags.name
| extend NodeDisk = strcat(Device, "/", HostName)
| order by NodeDisk asc, TimeGenerated asc
| serialize
| extend PrevVal = iif(prev(NodeDisk) != NodeDisk, 0.0, prev(Val)), PrevTimeGenerated = iif(prev(NodeDisk) != NodeDisk, datetime(null), prev(TimeGenerated))
| where isnotnull(PrevTimeGenerated) and PrevTimeGenerated != TimeGenerated
| extend Rate = iif(PrevVal > Val, Val / (datetime_diff('Second', TimeGenerated, PrevTimeGenerated) * 1), iif(PrevVal == Val, 0.0, (Val - PrevVal) / (datetime_diff('Second', TimeGenerated, PrevTimeGenerated) * 1)))
| where isnotnull(Rate)
| project TimeGenerated, NodeDisk, Rate
| render timechart**
```

Kinldy help

[image]

Comment: For the error message, try to add a new line like `| summarize AggregatedValue = avg(NodeDisk) by bin(TimeGenerated, 15m), Rate`?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way helped me create an alert successfully:

- Navigate to: Azure Portal > Kubernetes Services > {your cluster} > Logs
- Paste the query in the query editor
- Click on **+ New alert rule**

  [image: Logs]
- Configure other details (Condition, Action etc.) and create the alert

  [image: Create alert]